# IntelliJ 2019.1 Ultimate not redeploying changes

Tags: intellij-idea, websphere

I have a java/jsp app running websphere 8.5.5.5. When I change code, the code does not appear upon redeploying the code. I've searched the web and have tried hot-swapping, tried deleting old copies of the ear in the target folder, tried removing the ear artifact and re-adding it, tried the exploded and non-exploded artifact settings, and otherwise pretty much gone thru all the IntelliJ configuration settings. I've located all copies of the ear that keeps getting deployed (that's not found in the target folder) and renamed the folders they sit in, stopped/re-started IntelliJ but nothing affects the problem. it I'm at a total loss.

I need new/fresh ideas.

Comment: Please try the current IDE version and the clean server installation. See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html.

Comment: I did an experiment - I made a simple code change to my app (from a separate copy of my app's code) in my RAD IDE, built/started server in RAD and saw my change in running my app. I then shutdown RAD, double-checked I couldn't start my app in websphere. Went to IntelliJ IDE, ran the server from there and saw my RAD changes showing up in my app in websphere. Somehow IntelliJ is picking up the latest EAR from my RAD changes even though IntelliJ creates the EAR in an entirely different location. Why is IntelliJ using the EAR from the RAD location?

Comment: To CrazyCoder's comment - I'm currently prevented from upgrading to latest IntelliJ version per our company's software policy. I've submitted a request to allow the latest version to be added to our library of acceptable software. Don't know when / if request will be approved so I need other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I finally 'fingered' it out. Here's what I did-

1. In RAD, I started the server and opened the admin console. Navigate to where the EAR is defined and change it to point to the IntelliJ target folder (where IntelliJ deposits the new EAR each time you start the server from within IntelliJ). Save that setting.
2. In RAD, right-click on the server (in the server console tab) and select 'Add and Remove'. Select your app's current EAR in the configured frame and click the '< Remove' button.

After doing that, I was finally able to make a code change in IntelliJ and simply select to run my configured websphere. My code changes now appear.

The thing I did NOT try was not doing step 1 but only doing step 2. It's important enough for me that it's working. If you try just doing step 2 and it does work, then let us know - anything to simplify the process.

Enjoy!